# Reference web component root attribute with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

Created a web component with a shadow DOM. When the button is clicked it adds the `open` attribute to the web component.

I would like to show the hidden div in the CSS when the `open` is added with CSS styling. Is it possible for the shadow DOM styles to reference attributes on the web component root? Otherwise, I have to add a superfluous class or attribute within the shadow DOM.

```js
class CustomComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.element = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['open'];  
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[attrName] = this.hasAttribute(attrName);
    }
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    const template = document.getElementById('custom-component');
    const node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    this.element.appendChild(node);
    
    this.element.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.setAttribute('open', '');
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-component', CustomComponent);
```

```html
<template id="custom-component">
  <style>
    div {
      display: none;
    }
    [open] div {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <button>Open</button>
  <div>Content</div>
</template>

<custom-component></custom-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the `host` CSS pseudo selector is designed to handle this precise situation.

```js
class CustomComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.element = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['open'];  
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[attrName] = this.hasAttribute(attrName);
    }
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    const template = document.getElementById('custom-component');
    const node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    this.element.appendChild(node);
    
    this.element.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.setAttribute('open', '');
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-component', CustomComponent);
```

```html
<template id="custom-component">
  <style>
    div {
      display: none;
    }
    :host([open]) div {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <button>Open</button>
  <div>Content</div>
</template>

<custom-component></custom-component>
```